# Can we justify the behavior "taking derivative w.r.t. a variable"?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I have come across many times about this situation, which indicates that derivative of a function can be dependent on the "variable" that you are concerned with, e.g. one of the expression of the Chain Rule:(assume that all following functions are differentiable) 
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{dy}{du} \cdot \frac{du}{dx}
$$
What does $\displaystyle \frac{dy}{dx}$ and $\displaystyle \frac{dy}{du}$ mean? But with the other expression, if we can write $y=f \circ u$, then $y'=(f' \circ u)\cdot u'$. And by contrasting them, we know that $\displaystyle y'= \frac{dy}{dx}$ and $\displaystyle \frac{dy}{du} = f' \circ u, \frac{du}{dx} = u'$. In my opinion, $\displaystyle \frac{dy}{du}$ tends to misleading people, since we are using functions $f$ and $u$ rather than function $y$, and I  think the derivative of a function is uniquely determined, regardless of its "variable".
So, are there insights with which one can justify this behabior?

Comment: It is just a matter of notations. As you said, the derivative is uniquely definite. But the chain rule is a nice theorem and with this notation, it is easy to remember it. The key is knowing that we are abusing a bit of the notations : if you know what you're doing, then you can write whatever you want.

Comment: @DIdier_The fact is, only after quite a long time since I first learnt the Chain Rule did I know what exactly I am doing...

Comment: Sure. I am not using this notation and I agree with you. But if people want to use it, that's not a big deal if they know what they're doing.

Comment: I agree this notation... sucks. Particularly when using the chain rule for expressions like $F(x,f(x)).$ 

To answer what the expressions mean, I think it's pretty simple: use the limit definition of derivative. It turns out that $dy/du$ has nothing to do with $u$ at all (just a dummy variable), only $du/dx$ really has something to do with $u.$

Comment: @DIdier_I am currently studying Differential Equations With Applications and Historical Notes by G.F.Simmons, and I found these notations are almost everywhere. Quite annoying.

Comment: But notice your notation is extremely annoying if you have a function $f(a(b(c(g(x))))).$ You just need to have the correct context, then the chain rule notation that is annoying (without context) is much simpler to write: the $x$ derivative is just $$\frac{df}{dx}=\frac{df}{da}\frac{da}{db}\frac{db}{dc}\frac{dc}{dg}\frac{dg}{dx}.$$

Comment: @MaximGilula I think that's a good one, everything returns to definition.

Comment: Sorry for the spam... It may also help you to fill in the inputs of each function. This really clears up a lot of confusion. For example, $\frac{df}{da}$ is $\frac{df}{da}(a(b(c(g(x))))).$ It's really the inputs that are important here, in my opinion.

Comment: @MaximGilula hmm, interesting..